# Does Kafka Streams have a retention period concept for key value state stores?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on a project using Kafka Streams and I'm using a key value state store to store some data for my application. I need to be able to configure a retention period for the state store so that data older than a certain amount of time is automatically deleted.

I'm familiar with the concept of retention period in Kafka topics, but I'm not sure if there's a similar concept for Kafka Streams state stores. Specifically, I'm wondering if there's a way to set a retention period for a key value state store, similar to the retention period for a windowed state store.